Necessary and sufficiency condition for congruence of two isometric surfaces with strictly negative curvature.
In the book 'Differential and Riemannian Geometry" by Detlef Laugwitz, section 17.4 pg(215), the following is described : Given two isometric surfaces $S$ and $\widetilde{S}$, with metric coefficients $g_{ik}$ and coefficients of the second fundamental form being $L_{ik}$ and $\widetilde{L}_{ik}$, respectively, define the quantity $$A_{ik} := L_{ik} - \widetilde{L}_{ik}.$$
Let $S$ and $\widetilde{S}$ have Gaussian curvature $K \geq 0$ and the set of parabolic points be nowhere dense, then $S$ and $\widetilde{S}$ are congruent if and only if $\det(A_{ik})=0$.
Now my question is about the remark that follows this theorem, where it is said that Rembs and Grotemeyer prove an analogous result for surfaces with $K < 0$. But I have doubts about the sufficiency part in this case. I can come up with an example of an isometric deformation of a ruled surface such as a circular helicoid into another ruled surface, where the two surfaces are isometric but not congruent although $\det(A_{ik})=0$. I would really appreciate if someone can shed light on what I am missing here? A proof of this result for the case of $K<0$ is also most welcome, as I was unable to prove it.
